# How to cleanup sources to rebuild package with dpkg-buildpackage?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, dpkg

I'm playing with dpkg, but I got rather strange problem: Package can not be build second time after 1st package was successfully build.

```
dpkg-buildpackage -sa
....
dpkg-source: warning: newly created empty file 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/neutron/api/__init__.py' will not be represented in diff
(repeats 100500 times for different files).
```

How can I to rebuild deb second time?

It looks like I miss some cleanup command.

Answer (score 16):

the `debian/rules` file is actually a `Makefile`, and it *MUST* (according to the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules)) have a *clean* target to cleanup the build.

if this target is not run automatically, you can call it explictely with something like:

```
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -Tclean
```

Comment: But `dpkg-buildpackage` already runs this target, doesn't it?

Comment: I done this, and even remove all *.pyc files, and remove build directory. Now it failing with dpkg-source: info: local changes detected, the modified files are:
 neutron-2013.2.3/neutron.egg-info/entry_points.txt
 neutron-2013.2.3/neutron.egg-info/requires.txt
dpkg-source: info: you can integrate the local changes with dpkg-source --commit
   ...seems package is broken. Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee afaik it *should* run the `clean` target *before* starting the build (rather than *after* the build)

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin in this case: yes, probably the package is broken. you might have more luck by getting the [package via git](git://anonscm.debian.org/openstack/neutron.git) and just make sure that the git-tree is clean before rebuilding...

Comment: Right; but then the OP wold not be getting this error in the first place if it actually worked, right?

Comment: `man dpkg-buildpackage`: "If one or more specific targets have been selected with the -T or
           --target option, it calls those targets and stops here. Otherwise
           it runs the preclean hook and calls fakeroot debian/rules clean to
           clean the build-tree (unless -nc or --no-pre-clean is specified)."

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `debuild` instead of calling `dpkg-buildpackage` directly.
Simplest method is to build the binary packages along with unsigned source and unsigned changelog, cd to the `debian/` directory of the source and:

```
$ debuild -uc -us
```

You can call the `clean` target on `debuild` to clean up.

```
$ debuild -T clean
```

Comment: The command `debuild clean` doesn't appear to work without the `-T` flag first.  It passes this to `dpkg-buildpackage` directly, as shown in the error: `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -sa clean`
`dpkg-buildpackage: error: unknown option or argument clean`

Adding the `-T` flag first works:  `debuild -T clean`  gives: `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -sa -T clean`,  and then shows that it runs the `clean` target of `debian/rules`: `fakeroot debian/rules clean`

Answer (score 2):

The `debian/rules` file is usually set up to clean out old build artefacts, but yours seems to have a bug, or simply lack this functionality. (Submit a bug report?)

Without more knowledge about your package, this is speculative, but try removing the `build` directory.

In the worst case, start over by unpacking the sources anew.

Comment: A lot of packages are broken in this way. From the three general purpose answers here, this is the only one that is correct. See also https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/DebianSourcePackageBuildExplosion

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help.

In my case problem was spitted into two parts:

- uncleaned files (and original package has no proper cleaning rules)
- Incorrectly packed neutron_2013.2.3.orig.tar.gz, with neutron.egg-info (it even added to .gitignore on repo on github)

So in my case solution was rather complex:

1. Repack neutron_2013.2.3.orig.tar.gz without neutron.egg-info
2. Change md5sum/sha1sum/sha256sum and filesizes in neutron_2013.2.3-0ubuntu1~cloud0.dsc
3. Unpack source again with dpkg-source -x neutron_2013.2.3-0ubuntu1~cloud0.dsc
4. (patch/bump version)
5. dpkg-buildpackage -sa
6. To pack again, remove in neutron-2013.2.3:

   1. rm -r build neutron.egg-info
   2. find . -name "*.py" | xargs rm
7. dpkg-buildpackage -sa